# Conda crashes after installing one package - OSError: /lib64/liblzma.so.5: version `XZ_5.2' not found

Tags: python, crash, hpc, miniconda

I used `coda` for a long time, with limited problems.
However, I recently installed Miniconda2 (`Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh`) on a HPC node.
Everything works fine, but I can not install multiple packages.
What happens, is that I install one package, and after that, I get the following error when I try to install a new one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/hpc-home/ro/miniconda2/bin/conda", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/hpc-home/ro/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 150, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/hpc-home/ro/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1335, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/hpc-home/ro/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1046, in __call__
    return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/hpc-home/ro/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1090, in handle_exception
    return self.handle_unexpected_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/hpc-home/ro/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1101, in handle_unexpected_exception
    self.print_unexpected_error_report(error_report)
  File "/hpc-home/ro/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1171, in print_unexpected_error_report
    from .cli.main_info import get_env_vars_str, get_main_info_str
  File "/hpc-home/ro/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..core.index import _supplement_index_with_system
  File "/hpc-home/ro/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "/hpc-home/ro/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 15, in <module>
    from conda_package_handling.api import InvalidArchiveError
  File "/hpc-home/ro/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_package_handling/api.py", line 3, in <module>
    from libarchive.exception import ArchiveError as _LibarchiveArchiveError
  File "/hpc-home/ro/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libarchive/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .entry import ArchiveEntry
  File "/hpc-home/ro/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libarchive/entry.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import ffi
  File "/hpc-home/ro/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libarchive/ffi.py", line 27, in <module>
    libarchive = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libarchive_path)
  File "/hpc-home/ro/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 444, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/hpc-home/ro/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /lib64/liblzma.so.5: version `XZ_5.2' not found (required by /hpc-home/ro/miniconda2/lib/libarchive.so.13)
```

The problem is temporally fixed when I re-install `conda`:
`bash  Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -u`

I am not sure what I am missing here. Would someone point me towards a potential solution not involving using `sudo`, as I have no rights?

Comment: You seem to need a *liblzma* upgrade.

Comment: @CristiFati thanks very much. Not sure hot to update that with no `sudo` rights

Comment: You could install a newer version in your path (where you're able to write). Or you could build it from sources :).

Comment: If installing a package breaks conda, then you should show us the installation report of that package. Switch to Miniconda3 instead of 2, Python 2 is going out of support soon. Try running `conda update conda` immediately after installation.